# Find lines in file that contain duplicate characters

Tags: bash, sorting, duplicates, character

I need some help in locating lines in a text file that contain duplicate characters. 
I prefer using bash, but any other method will do fine :)

A small example just to make things clear:
file.txt:

```
1234
11234
abcd
12234
ab321
1233
zs11w
12w2
```

the desired output:

```
11234
12234
1233
zs11w
12w2
```

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 11):

```
grep '\(.\).*\1' file.txt
```

Matches any line that contains a character, any string, and then that same character, i.e. any line with duplicates.

Comment: My pleasure to +1 this very elegant and informatory answer. I didn't know that grep could address subexpressions too!

Comment: That's great! Can you also help me locate lines that contain 3 or more duplicate characters? for example as333fdt

Comment: `grep '\(.\).*\1.*\1' file.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Perl:

```
perl -ne 'print if /(.)\1/' file.txt
```

awk:

```
awk -F "" '{for (i=1; i<NF; i++) if ($i == $(i+1)) {print; next}}' flie.txt
```